# Redis cluster creation with no master and slave

Tags: redis

Is there any possibility in creation of cluster with no master and slave and every node can access any node in the cluster using REDIS ?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by `every node can access any node in the cluster using REDIS ?`

Comment: I want to generate a cluster like peer to peer kind of rather than master and slave

Comment: Then do not specify any node as a replica node. Replicas are optional

Comment: http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial?

Comment: @BasitAnwer If we dont specify "replica" config, every node is individual instance. That's not a cluster!